# How can I fix issues in Windows 11 without uninstalling programs when SFC and DISM fail

Tags: windows-11, dism, sfc

*Disclosure: My system does not meet the requirements for Windows 11 and was installed by bypassing requirements.*

I have been experiencing numerous problems with my system including failed Windows Apps, blue screens, and updates that will not complete. I have apps that I need to keep installed, so I don't want to do a full system restart.

I tried SFC and it said that it cannot repair the system.

I ran DISM and it says it cannot find the source.

I tried the following:

- [mounting a Windows Image](https://www.minitool.com/news/fix-dism-source-files-could-not-be-found-win10.html) and using that.
- [extracting the WIM file](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-convert-install-wim-to-install-esd-or-vice-versa) from the ESD in the image and using that.
- Running the Windows Update troubleshooter.

I also tried doing an in-place upgrade using the Windows Disc Image, but when the option of "Choose what to keep" appears it only allows, "Nothing." The note on the screen reads:

> Your files, apps, and settings can't be kept because your current
> version of Windows might be installed in an unsupported directory, or
> you're trying to install an older version of Windows.

But, my Windows is installed to the 'C' directory in a normal manner and while it may be an older version of Windows, it is the image generated by the Windows 11 Media Creation Tool, so I don't know how I would get a newer version.

Comment: As you state, you're running Windows 11 on a PC not designed to meet minimal standards. It's logical to expect issues, and, even if you fix the current ones, it's likely new issues will occur. What benefit does Windows 11 have over the previous Windows OS, or a new OS which the machine *should* be able to run, such as Linux?

Comment: “or you're trying to install an older version of Windows.” - So two questions, first what build exactly are you running, and what build are you attempting to install.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't even think to check. I am running 22h2(22621.2361) and the ISO is 10.0.19041 build 3803. So I guess I need to try and find a newer ISO, first.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Windows 11 actually runs much better than 10. Also Linux simply doesn't have the support I need for this system.

Comment: @VCD_WL - Based on those builds your trying to downgrade to Windows 10 based on 19041 which can’t be done and keep your files.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because - The Title says it all.  There will be problems.  And more problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using [Rufus](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/bypass-windows-11-tpm-requirement). Rufus offers ISO downloads and bypassing the requirements all-in-one. Once I did this, Windows allowed me to do an in-place upgrade, which was the ideal solution.

I did try downloading a newer ISO from Microsoft, but it failed the requirement checks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have been here before.

This Microsoft page is very valuable in getting Windows 11 Preview Downloads.

[Windows 11 Insider information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/isos)

First be sure you have a complete backup of documents, email and files. Know where you can get your Apps. This is because you got a Keep Nothing warning.

Download a Windows 11 Insider ISO to a USB Key. Run setup.exe from the ISO and start and install / repair. At the appropriate point, Keep Nothing and let it proceed.

Before installing Apps or recovering data, ensure Windows 11 is running and try updating it.

I hope that works for you but do know that it is possible Windows 11 has outrun your computer. It may be necessary to go back to a very early version of Windows 11 or even Windows 10.